# How to move all files but not directores into a folder

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, mv

Say I have a folder with five files and one folder. What would be the linux terminal command to move all those files into that one sub-folder?

I've tried `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} destination_path \;` but I get the error `find: missing argument to -exec`

Comment: Try changing `{}` to `'{}'`. (Disclaimer: your command `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} destination_path \;` already works perfectly on my system, so I can't reproduce your issue to test fixes to it. But from the error message, I'm guessing that your shell is doing something to the unquoted `{}` that prevents `find` from seeing it.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's simply:

```
mv * destination_path
```

Comment: Woops, actually both worked. I thought the error would prevent any files from moving but actually both moved the files and works for this situation. If I had other sibling subfolders this wouldn't work though, since it would move those as well. Thanks both.

Comment: This doesn't work at all and will move the entire current directory, INCLUDING FOLDERS, to `destination_path`

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
( shopt -s extglob; mv !(destination_path) destination_path )
```